# Multiple entries of PCIe address range in /proc/mem log

Tags: pci-e

I use `dma_alloc_coherent()` in my custom driver to get both virtual and bus addresses.

```
res->KernelAddress = (u64)dma_alloc_coherent( &DevExt->pdev->dev, size, &res->BusAddress, GFP_ATOMIC );
```

When printing (%llx) the bus address (res->BusAddress), I got 80009000 as the one.
I checked the log of /proc/iomem to verify the range, but there are multiple entries.

The log of /proc/iomem is shown below:

```
10000000-10000fff : /pcie-controller@10003000/pci@1,0
10003000-100037ff : pcie-pads
10003800-10003fff : pcie-afi
10004000-10004fff : /pcie-controller@10003000/pci@3,0
40000000-4fffffff : pcie-config-space
50100000-57ffffff : pcie-non-prefetchable
  50800000-52ffffff : PCI Bus 0000:01
    50800000-5087ffff : 0000:01:00.0
    51000000-51ffffff : 0000:01:00.0
    52000000-52ffffff : 0000:01:00.0
58000000-7fffffff : pcie-prefetchable
  58000000-58ffffff : PCI Bus 0000:01
    58000000-58ffffff : 0000:01:00.0
80000000-d82fffff : System RAM
  80080000-810fafff : Kernel code
  8123f000-814b3fff : Kernel data
d9300000-efffffff : System RAM
f0200000-275ffffff : System RAM
276600000-2767fffff : System RAM
```

1. Is 80009000 valid? Which section does it belong to?
2. Is it necessary to use `dma_mmap_coherent()` after `dma_alloc_coherent()` for proper mapping?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/bus-virt-phys-mapping.txt (some of the details of this file are now obsolete but it's the best overview of the issue):

> Essentially, the three ways of addressing memory are (this is "real memory",
>   that is, normal RAM--see later about other details):
>
> - CPU untranslated.  This is the "physical" address.  Physical address 
>     0 is what the CPU sees when it drives zeroes on the memory bus.
> - CPU translated address. This is the "virtual" address, and is 
>     completely internal to the CPU itself with the CPU doing the appropriate
>     translations into "CPU untranslated".
> - bus address. This is the address of memory as seen by OTHER devices, 
>     not the CPU. Now, in theory there could be many different bus 
>     addresses, with each device seeing memory in some device-specific way, but
>     happily most hardware designers aren't actually actively trying to make
>     things any more complex than necessary, so you can assume that all 
>     external hardware sees the memory the same way.
>
> Now, on normal PCs the bus address is exactly the same as the physical
>   address, and things are very simple indeed. However, they are that simple
>   because the memory and the devices share the same address space, and that is
>   not generally necessarily true on other PCI/ISA setups.

The bottom line is that the answer to your question is architecture-dependent.

In your `/proc/iomem` snippet, note that that that listing is nested. The `80009000` address appears to fall into two sections because one of those sections is a subset of the other. *If* that address was a physical memory address, then yes, it would be a "kernel code address", which would be a strange thing to get back from `dma_alloc_coherent`. That leads me to believe that a physical address is *not* the same as a bus address on your architecture.

`dma_alloc_coherent` also maps the memory in kernel virtual address space so you shouldn't need to do anything else to access it from your code. (`dma_mmap_coherent` is used to map the memory into user virtual address space.)

Comment: Isnt dma_alloc_coherent () give bus addr and virtual addr?Our custom application requires the physical addr.

Comment: How would your application use the physical address? The *only* way you can use a physical address is to create a virtual address that maps to it. That is already done for you (for kernel space) by `dma_alloc_coherent` and can be done for user-space with `dma_mmap_coherent`.

Comment: Physical address is used by remap_pfn_range () for mapping. With SMMU disabled, there was no issue in getting the physical address with virt_to_phys (). But now that SMMU is ON, an alternative to calculate the physical address must be found. You mean to say that dma_alloc_coherent and dma_mmap_coherent are the same but the scope is different? But how to map the virtual address returned by dma_mmap_coherent to get the physical address?

Comment: After calling `dma_alloc_coherent`, you should be able to pass its return values to `dma_mmap_coherent` in order to map the memory to user space. The latter function ultimately calls `remap_pfn_range` *for you*. See `include/linux/dma-mapping.h` for the source and follow code from there. (Helps to learn to use tags: run `make tags` in kernel source hierarchy, then use your editor to chase tags.)

Comment: Vendor provided driver and application flow is something like this: 1. dma_alloc_coherent, 2. virt_to_phys 3. mmap (phys_add, kern_addr) 4. remap_pfn_range(). I tried using dma_mmap_coherent() in the place of remap_pfn_range(), but resulted in page fault error. Does vma struct hold dma_addr_t info? I wonder if intermediate mmap (phys_addr, kern_addr) creates issues. This flow works when there is no SMMU. Also, custom driver has multiple intermediate files which are not well organized. Is streaming DMA better than coherent DMA where virt_to_phys() can be used for getting the physical addr.

Comment: Can you please comment on this?